# Is there a graceful way to stop svnserve -d

Tags: svn, svnserve

I'm looking for something like:

```
svnserve stop
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The recommended way is to do it is by using the `kill` command which will allow subversion to shut down properly.  I don't think there is any better way to do it.

Comment: On *nix, kill w/o any special options will instruct the program to do a graceful shutdown.  On Windows, I think it will terminate with extreme prejudice...  if you have a terminal window open where you launched the thing, you can always use Ctrl+C

Comment: This is true but if you were running svnserve on Windows you should really be running it as a service instead of using -d in which case you would just use the Service Manager to shut it down.

Comment: The kill command defaults to signal 15, which sends a TERM signal to the process and terminate properly. Uness you don't do a `kill -9 svnserve` the shutdown should be clean.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `start-stop-daemon` program to do it :

```
/sbin/start-stop-daemon --stop --exec /usr/bin/svnserve
```

To start it :

```
 /sbin/start-stop-daemon --start --chuid svn:svn --exec /usr/bin/svnserve -- -d -r /var/svn
```

Of course you can adapt user and group (`svn:svn`), and the SVN root path (`/var/svn`)

These scripts are part of another one located in `/etc/init.d/svnserve` that I use on all my SVN servers to manage the daemon. See [this Ubuntu doc](http://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/subversion) for more explanations.

Answer (score 5):

you can use the command :  ***ps aux | grep svnserve*** to get the svnserve process ID  
then : kill -9 [ID_of_svnserve_process]

Answer (score 0):

also ps aux | grep -e PID -e svnserve may be useful to show titles.